# Won't login, resolution off, screen flickers

Tags: login

So, since last restart my Ubuntu won't log in, it just loops.

Here's a video of what happens:
https://youtu.be/XS4j4M8HLCM

Ive tried to follow a few tutorials and solutions like making a new Xauthority file but so far no luck.

Also, the resolution is weird.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had the same issue in the past. I recommend installing and using GDM. You can do this by typing

```
sudo apt install gdm3
```

Logout and choose gdm. Tell me if this fixes your issue too. Or type

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and then choose `gdm3`.

Comment: Oh crap, I installed and used gdm3 like you said and now it's even worse. Here's a video of what's happening: https://youtu.be/nP873BiU_m0 It let's me get into the console or shell  (alt ctrl f3) for a second before it flashes green again and I have to ctrl alt f3 back in. It gives me enough time to run commands and hopefully fix it though

Comment: Could you login. Maybe restart gdm and if that doesent work try a reboot. I'll have to think this through a bit more if that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Ive already tried to restart the computer a couple times. What would be the command to restart gdm? Thanks so much for your help btw

Comment: You can try `service gdm3 restart`. Probably wont help though if you rebooted and tried to login already through gdm, but it cant hurt at this point. I believe the problem you are receiving at this point has to deal with the drivers for your screen. Have you been able to use Ubuntu in the past without issues?

Comment: what kind of display board are you using?nvidia?  lspci |grep VGA

Comment: (...) *now it's even worse* is not surprising, at all. Please follow the instructions answered in the duplicate mentioned in your question comments. Installing something else instead of fixing what's already there, that worked in the past and *should* work now, is perhaps something users learns in Windows but hardly applicable here.

Comment: OK, so some updates. This is the first time this has happened to me, with no other, similar errors. I went back to it to run that gdm3 restart command, and was surprised by the fact that it was no longer flashing and doing the thing. So, I figured maybe it let me log in so I pressed ctrl alt f7. All it says after that is [   ***] A start job is running for Hold unt...ess finishes up (22s / no limit). Also I have a nvidia EVGA GEFORCE GTX 750Ti graphics card.

Comment: @MichaelBay I've already been to that thread and tried most of those solutions, as well as a few other sources. I'm stumped, or else I wouldn't have made this new thread.

Comment: Alright so I restarted gdm and now it's back to doing the flashing thing again.

Comment: i faced similar problem with you made a video three days ago, what i did is ctrl+f7 and going back command line and sync nvidia display board with new kernel 4.10.0.27, pls try out to upgrade your system....

Comment: I agree. Make sure your system is up to date. Don't leave out the idea of reinstalling your drivers.

Comment: OK, but I'm not familiar with the commands to do all that with. Should I just Google "how to sync nvidia display board with new kernel" I guess?

Comment: I am suggesting that you search for your drivers and download them and install those. This sounds like the solution to your problem.

Comment: Also, can I safely change back to lightdm to fix this flashing? And OK I'll start figuring out how to do that driver stuff and all.

Comment: @Turtled pls make a command sudo apt-get upgrade firstly, after then i agree with nerdofcode about drivers

Comment: @solfish You are suppose to run `sudo apt update` first to update your repositories then `sudo apt upgrade` to do the actual update to the system.

Comment: Yes! That upgrade command took a few hours but it worked. Thanks so much, guys! Now to buy Windows...

Comment: @Turtled Glad we could help